# How to put countdown timer in each rows of the list view?

Tags: c#, listview, timer

I have this form:

[image]

Is it possible to get the value of ETA column and implement a countdown on all of the rows in the listview?

what i wanted to do is that after "1 minute" has expired it will show a message box.

Comment: You should update a property of the items you are presenting.

Comment: what do you mean? im sorry but im new to c#, im not yet well aware of the properties or so.

Comment: It is not a good idea to maintain a bunch of timers (as you mentioned one for each row). How about a timer for all rows? At the timer's Tick event, calculate the count down value for each row. What Jeroen suggested is an idea of data binding, with which you simply need to calculate the count down value, the listview will be updated automatically.